# Collapse down calendar table by grouping like fields

Tags: sql, t-sql, calendar

I have a script that generates a calendar table and fills in the public holidays and weekends for England and Wales. I would like to have the non working days as start and end periods, so taking the input

```
1980-04-01 00:00:00.000 Tuesday         0
1980-04-02 00:00:00.000 Wednesday   0
1980-04-03 00:00:00.000 Thursday    0
1980-04-04 00:00:00.000 Friday          1
1980-04-05 00:00:00.000 Saturday    1
1980-04-06 00:00:00.000 Sunday          1
1980-04-07 00:00:00.000 Monday          1
1980-04-08 00:00:00.000 Tuesday         0
1980-04-09 00:00:00.000 Wednesday   0
```

It would give the output

```
Start      end
1980-04-03 1980-04-08
```

in other words, the day before the first non working day and the day after the last non working day of the group. To do this I would presumably use a min and max with a group and dateadd, but how do I go about obtaining a unique number to group each set of days by? This is using 2008 R2.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#calendar', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #calendar
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#easter', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #easter; 


-- CREATE TABLE CALENDAR

CREATE TABLE #calendar
(
    [CalendarDate] DATETIME,
       dayofwk varchar(20),
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME




--INPUTS GO HERE
SET @StartDate = '01-01-1980'
SET @EndDate = '31-12-2018'


DECLARE @Startyear int
DECLARE @endyear int
set @startyear = YEAR(@StartDate)
set @endyear = YEAR(@EndDate)

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #calendar
             (
                   CalendarDate, dayofwk
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate, datename(dw,@startdate)

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
      END



---CREATE LIST OF EASTER MONDAY & GOOD FRIDAYS

create table #easter(
eastersunday_goodfriday  date)


DECLARE     @y int,
@EpactCalc INT,  
        @PaschalDaysCalc INT, 
        @NumOfDaysToSunday INT, 
        @EasterMonth INT, 
        @EasterDay INT


WHILE @Startyear <= @endyear
      BEGIN

    SET @y = @startyear
    SET @EpactCalc = (24 + 19 * (@Y % 19)) % 30 
    SET @PaschalDaysCalc = @EpactCalc - (@EpactCalc / 28) 
    SET @NumOfDaysToSunday = @PaschalDaysCalc - ( 
        (@Y + @Y / 4 + @PaschalDaysCalc - 13) % 7 
    ) 

    SET @EasterMonth = 3 + (@NumOfDaysToSunday + 40) / 44 

    SET @EasterDay = @NumOfDaysToSunday + 28 - ( 
        31 * (@EasterMonth / 4) 
    ) 

       insert into #easter

       SELECT dateadd(d,-2, CONVERT 
        (  SMALLDATETIME, 
                 RTRIM(@Y)  
            + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM(@EasterMonth), 2)  
            + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM(@EasterDay), 2)  ))

insert into #easter

       SELECT dateadd(d,1, CONVERT 
        (  SMALLDATETIME, 
                 RTRIM(@Y)  
            + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM(@EasterMonth), 2)  
            + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM(@EasterDay), 2)  ))

             SET @Startyear =@Startyear +1

                     end




select calendardate, dayofwk,
--NEW YEAR'S DAY
case
when day(calendardate) = 1 and month(calendardate) = 1 and dayofwk not in ('Saturday', 'sunday') then 1
when day(calendardate) between 2 and 3 and month(calendardate) = 1 and dayofwk = 'Monday' then 1

--GOOD FRIDAY, EASTER MONDAY
WHEN eastersunday_goodfriday IS NOT NULL THEN 1

--EARLY MAY BANK HOLIDAY
WHEN (datepart(weekday, CALENDARDATE) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7 + 1 = 1   
and (datepart(day, CALENDARDATE) - 1) / 7 + 1 = 1 
AND MONTH(CALENDARDATE) = 5 
THEN 1

--LATE MAY BANK HOLIDAY
WHEN (datepart(weekday, CALENDARDATE) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7 + 1 = 1   
and (datepart(day, CALENDARDATE) - 1) / 7 + 1 = 4 
AND MONTH(CALENDARDATE) = 5 
THEN 1

--LATE AUGUST BANK HOLIDAY
WHEN (datepart(weekday, CALENDARDATE) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7 + 1 = 1   
and (datepart(day, CALENDARDATE) - 1) / 7 + 1 = 4 
AND MONTH(CALENDARDATE) = 8 
THEN 1

--CHRISTMAS DAY
WHEN DAY(CalendarDate) = 25 AND MONTH(CALENDARDATE) = 12 AND dayofwk NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') THEN 1 

--BOXING DAY
WHEN DAY(CalendarDate) = 26 AND MONTH(CALENDARDATE) = 12 AND dayofwk NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') THEN 1 
WHEN DAY(CalendarDate) between 27 and 28 AND MONTH(CALENDARDATE) = 12 AND DAYOFWK IN ('MONDAY','TUESDAY') THEN 1 

--SAT&SUN
WHEN DATENAME(DW,CALENDARDATE) IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') THEN 1


ELSE 0 
end as ISNONWORKINGDAY 
                     from #calendar c 
                     left join #easter e 
                     on c.calendardate = e.eastersunday_goodfriday
                     ORDER BY C.CALENDARDATE
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The join's to the table are going to be much for efficient with equijoins rather than non-equijoins.

Answer (score 0):

This seams like a typical island problem. Given what you posted you could do this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (dt DATE, isNonWorkDay BIT);
INSERT @table(dt,isNonWorkDay)
VALUES
('1980-04-01', 0),
('1980-04-02', 0),
('1980-04-03', 0),
('1980-04-04', 1),
('1980-04-05', 1),
('1980-04-06', 1),
('1980-04-07', 1),
('1980-04-08', 0),
('1980-04-09', 0);

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,MIN(t.dt)), DATEADD(DAY,1,MAX(t.dt))
FROM @table t
WHERE t.isNonWorkDay = 1;
```

**Returns**: 1980-04-03, 1980-04-08

For multiple islands you could do this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (dt DATE, isNonWorkDay BIT);
INSERT @table(dt,isNonWorkDay)
VALUES
('1980-04-01', 0),
('1980-04-02', 0),
('1980-04-03', 0),
('1980-04-04', 1),
('1980-04-05', 1),
('1980-04-06', 1),
('1980-04-07', 1),
('1980-04-08', 0),
('1980-04-09', 0),
('1980-04-10', 0),
('1980-04-11', 1),
('1980-04-12', 1),
('1980-04-13', 1),
('1980-04-14', 0),
('1980-04-15', 0);

WITH x AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.dt)
  FROM @table t
),
xx AS 
(
  SELECT *, grouper = x.rn - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.dt)
  FROM x
  WHERE x.isNonWorkDay = 1
)
SELECT dtStart = DATEADD(DAY,-1,MIN(xx.dt)),  dtend = DATEADD(DAY,1,MAX(xx.dt))
FROM xx
GROUP BY xx.grouper;
```

Returns:

```
dtStart    dtend
---------- ----------
1980-04-03 1980-04-08
1980-04-10 1980-04-14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the difference of a consecutive numbering of all days and a consecutive numbering of all non-workingdays to use for the grouping.
For a consecutive group of non-workingdays, these differences will all have the same value, and because of the gaps (workingsdays) between the groups, the next group will have a different (higher) value.

For numbering all days, you can use DATEDIFF, for the numbering of non-workingdays you can use ROW_NUMBER. The query could look like this:

```
WITH
  numbering (calendardate, grp_num) AS (
    SELECT 
      calendardate,
      DATEDIFF(day, 0, calendardate) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY calendardate)
    FROM YourTable WHERE ISNONWORKINGDAY = 1
  )
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, -1, MIN(calendardate)) AS StartDate,
    DATEADD(day, +1, MAX(calendardate)) AS EndDate
FROM numbering GROUP BY grp_num;
```